# Incorporating BBCode in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, bbcode

Is it possible to incorporate BBcode in Laravel 4? Im creating a blog site with admin and user side and I want to try using bbcode to embed images and videos in the user side. If not, do you know other ways to do this (embed images and videos)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i once used [golonka/BBCodeParser](https://github.com/golonka/BBCodeParser) package, which did the job perfectly.